# What is the best place to update the state in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle, setstate

Currently I am updating my state in `componentDidUpdate` life cycle function. But then my app is sending continuous GET request because of the nature of that function,so I am not sure which place to update the state so I can avoid that.

Following is my code.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.id){
        if(!this.props.loadedPost || (this.state.loadedPost && this.state.loadedPost.ID !== this.props.id)){
            axios.get('https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/xhehehshs.wordpress.com/posts/'+this.props.id)
            .then( response => {
                this.setState({ loadedPost: response.data });
            });
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Component Will Mount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is a bad place to be doing an AJAX call and updating the state, since well... It is called every time the component gets updated (so stuff like this.setState({}) will trigger it over and over again).

`componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount` are the better places to make that call if you want it to be done right before it mounts or as soon as the component mounts.

Edit: After seeing your comment on another answer regarding that you want this to be done after a click, once the component is already mounted. So here is a proposed solution for that:

```
getPosts () {
  if(this.props.id){
        if(!this.props.loadedPost || (this.state.loadedPost && 
  this.state.loadedPost.ID !== this.props.id)){
            axios.get('https://public-
  api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/ishhaanpatel.wordpress.com/posts/'+this.props.id)
            .then( response => {
                this.setState({ loadedPost: response.data });
            });
        }  
    }
}

 handleClick (target, value) {
    // do your magic
    this.getPosts() 
 }
```

Comment: oh nice! that's really helpful thank you sir @theJuls

Comment: There might be cases where one wants to make a call after some props change. I'm using [`componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle function and check for condition where `this.props` and `nextProps` are in state where another request needs to be sent. It's also called less frequently since it's not triggered by `this.state` changes, only by being passed new `props` value, i.e. being re-rendered within the parent component.

Answer (score 3):

componentDidMount is the ideal spot for AJAX calls. It only runs once right after the component mounts, so you can avoid the infinite loop you've created by making AJAX calls from there.

Here is a nice article explaining all the React lifecycle hooks and what to use them for: https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1

Comment: If I use `componentDidMount`, my app isn't even attempting that GET request.

Comment: Is your component already mounted when you want to trigger this GET request?

Comment: My component is already mounted actually, what I am doing here is when user click on some post, I am taking ID of the post from other component and using that id in this component to display full post.

Comment: @IshanPatel since that is the case, you should probably do it on the click action and not on one of the lifecycle methods.